# Can't see untracked files

Tags: git, github

I was having problems with git, and at some point ran a command that hides the untracked files. Now whenever I type 'git status' it only shows modified files. I have to type 'git status -u' to see the untracked files. How I can reset this to always show modified AND untracked files?

Answer (score 2):

One off...

```
git status --untracked-files=normal
```

Global/Permanent

```
git config status.showuntrackedfiles normal
```

Comment: I've tried this, now when I type git status it says: error: Invalid untracked files mode 'yes' fatal: bad config variable 'status.showuntrackedfiles' in file '.git/config' at line 27

Comment: This account is too new to upvote apparently. and I can only accept in 10 minutes :/

Comment: `git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles all`

Comment: @elmgo oh, forgot about the new account restriction and the 10 minute time limit is new to me; thanks for the comment